# Binding a Datagrid Columnheader Background to da datatable row

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I want to color my DataGrid ColumnHeader depending on a row in the datatable which is bound to the DataGrid.
But how can I do this? The method I have used on the Datagrid.Row does not work, because there is apparently no "Column" Property which I can ue.

I came up with this, so I can use the whole DataGrid in my Colorconverter, but I am unable to find a way to determine which Columnheader is currently rendered.

XAML:

```
   <DataGrid x:Name="excelDataTable_ExcelData">
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Converter={StaticResource ExcelColumnColorConverter}}"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid>
```

Code Behind Colorconverter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,   System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    var col = (System.Data.DataColumn)value;
    var colStateObj = col.Table.Rows[col.Table.Rows.Count-1][col.ColumnName];
    Enums.RowState colorValue = (Enums.RowState)Enum.Parse(typeof(Enums.RowState), colStateObj.ToString());

    switch (colorValue)
    {
        case Enums.RowState.HeaderRow:
            return Brushes.Gainsboro;
        case Enums.RowState.isIncluded:
            return Brushes.LightGreen;
        case Enums.RowState.NotIncluded:
            return Brushes.LightSalmon;
        default:
            return Brushes.Azure;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Converts the value of the hidden Color row to a color on the Data table.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">The value</param>
/// <param name="targetType">The type of the binding target.</param>
/// <param name="parameter">The converter parameter.</param>
/// <param name="culture">The culture</param>
/// <returns>
/// EThe converted value or NULL
/// </returns>
/// <exception cref="System.NotImplementedException">Not implemented because it is not needed</exception>
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: To determine the current column header - have you tried examining the current DataColumn's ColumnName within the converter?

Comment: @SandraWalters: Thank you for the Idea: I have tried that, but the CurrentColumn is null :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally foubnd a solution, using Multibinding:

XAML:

```
  <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ExcelColumnColorConverter}">
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}"></Binding>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource self}" Path="Column"></Binding>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
```

The Converter:

```
 public class ExcelColumnColorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
   public object Convert(object[] value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (!(value[1] == null))
            {
                var dgrid = (DataGrid)value[0];
                var colHeader = ((DataGridTextColumn)value[1]).Header.ToString();

                var dView = (System.Data.DataView)dgrid.ItemsSource;
                var table = dView.Table;

                var rowstateObj = table.Rows[table.Rows.Count - 1][colHeader];
                Enums.RowState colorValue = (Enums.RowState)Enum.Parse(typeof(Enums.RowState), rowstateObj.ToString());

                switch (colorValue)
                {
                    case Enums.RowState.HeaderRow:
                        return Brushes.Gainsboro;
                    case Enums.RowState.isIncluded:
                        return Brushes.LightGreen;
                    case Enums.RowState.NotIncluded:
                        return Brushes.LightSalmon;
                    default:
                        return Brushes.Azure;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
```